# <br/> doesn't break lines in all browsers

Tags: html

I know this seems odd, but on my websites `<br>` tags do not work normally. Consider this url http://barchick.com/most-wanted/camper-english. The content (WHERE DO YOU LIVE?San Francisco, California....) contains `<br/>` tags but browser skip that.

```
WHERE DO YOU LIVE?<br/><br/>San Francisco, California, USA.<br/><br/>
```

in browser I see jst `WHERE DO YOU LIVE?San Francisco, California`

What is the reason of that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `main.css` file, line 3913:

```
#wanted-single .text BR{
  display: none;
}
```

If you remove that rule you will see line breaks as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your doctype and/or browser `<br/>` isn't valid HTML. You need a space before the `/` to allow older browsers to understand the `<br>` tag properly: `<br />`

Comment: The actual source contains `<br />`.

Comment: "You need a space before the / to allow older browsers to understand the `<br>` tag properly:". It's nice that you're still thinking of those poor users still using Netscape 4 (The last browser to have this issue.)